# ESP32 to Raspberry Pi Pico W Wi-Fi connection too slow

Tags: c, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, arduino-esp32

I need a connection between an ESP32 and a Raspberry Pi Pico W to control an RC boat. The data transfer is too slow. Latency needs to be 0.1 seconds or less. My test was with 1 second delay, but the data received by Raspberry Pi Pico W isn't what I want:

```
Response from ESP32: 190, 300
Response from ESP32:

Response from ESP32: 190, 300
Response from ESP32:

Response from ESP32: 190, 300
Response from ESP32:
```

There's one line where response of ESP32 is missing. How to fix it? I used Arduino IDE to program the ESP32 and Thonny to program the Raspberry Pi Pico W.

ESP32:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const char* ssid = "YourSSID";
const char* password = "YourPassword";
const int serverPort = 1234;

WiFiServer server(serverPort);
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if (!client || !client.connected()) {
    client = server.available();
    if (client) {
      Serial.println("Client connected");
    }
  }

  if (client && client.connected()) {
    // Check if data is available from the Raspberry Pi Pico W
    if (client.available()) {
      String receivedData = client.readStringUntil('\n');
      Serial.println("Received data: " + receivedData);

      // Send a response back to the Raspberry Pi Pico W
      client.println("190, 300");
    }
  }
}
```

Raspberry Pi Pico W:

```
import usocket as socket
import network
import time

def main():
    ssid = "YourSSID"
    password = "YourPassword"
    esp32_ip = "YourESP32IP"  # Replace with the IP address of the ESP32
    esp32_port = 1234

    wifi = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wifi.active(True)
    wifi.connect(ssid, password)

    while not wifi.isconnected():
        time.sleep(1)

    print("Wi-Fi connected successfully")

    # Create a socket and connect to the ESP32
    client_socket = socket.socket()
    addr = socket.getaddrinfo(esp32_ip, esp32_port)[0][-1]
    client_socket.connect(addr)

    try:
        while True:
            # Send data to the ESP32
            data_to_send = "Hello from Raspberry Pi Pico W!"
            client_socket.send(data_to_send)

            # Receive the response from the ESP32
            response = client_socket.recv(1024)
            print("Response from ESP32:", response.decode())

            time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 0.1 seconds before sending more data

    except:
        print("Connection lost. Reconnecting...")
        client_socket.close()
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: time.sleep(1) is a whole second.

Answer (score 1):

Your question appears to be two-fold and I will attempt to answer both, but first list them beneath as a means of documentation for others.

### Question Breakdown

Your questions appear to be:

- Why does it take 1 second before I read the reply from the ESP32 on the Raspberry Pico?
- Why do I get an extra empty line on my pico's output?

### Answers

I'll start with the first answer.

As per the [documentation of the micropython time library](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/wifi/client.println/), the argument passed to `time.sleep` is the amount of seconds, as opposed to the commonly used `delay` function of the Arduino framework, which expects an integer amount of milliseconds. This argument does not have to be an integer number and should therefore in your case be 0.1, or less.

The second answer to the second question lies in the code used in the ESP32. In your code you use the statement `client.println("190, 300")` to send a message to the pico. As the [documentation of the WifiClient](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/wifi/client.println/) indicates, this method will append a carriage return (`\r`) and a newline (`\n`) to the passed argument, in that order. I assume the usocket `recv` function reads up to a carriage return, which would explain the extra output line (and the corresponding whiteline below), although I could not find any mentioning of this in the documentation. The easiest fix would be to either use the `client.print` statement on the ESP32 or check for empty messages on the pico.

I hope this helps; good luck!